# Can't use iTerm2 key bindings with Brave in foreground

Tags: macos, iterm, keybindings

I'm having an issue using my keybinds for iTerm2 windows. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> (C-S-space) as a primary bind. Earlier today, I used this keybind successfully, but at present, it doesn't work.

- Show/Hide toggling works when iTerm is in focus, and has at least 1 window currently open in addition to the window being toggled.
- Show/Hide toggling when Brave or other desktop applications are in focus does not show an iTerm window. However the Show/Hide (0/1-parity) state of the iTerm window is evident if I application-switch back to the iTerm application. Window(s) that I have toggled while iTerm was not the application in focus, are visible and in foregrounded LRU order, as would be expected in normal operation.

In other words, the state of showing/not-showing parity is correctly tracked, but iTerm windows do not pop up over other applications.

#### Environment

Same login session as working earlier. iTerm not recently updated.

#### Attempted

I have restarted iTerm2--no change in behavior.

##### Note:

On this or another StackExchange site, I've solved a different issue involving together iTerm and Brave. That issue related to AppleScript, Accessibility permissions, signed & entitled & recently opened applications. Issue observed was that Brave stopped responding to scripting commands, and osascript commands returned with an "application closed" or similar error message. I was able to check with a fresh, bare (no tmux) terminal in a newly reopened iTerm application. I was able to resolve by starting a new tmux server process, with a newly launched instance of iTerm as its parent.

I remember an OS update, or application update, an expiring of a macOS entitlement -- a permission in the application's plist. Restarting applications was a necessary part of the solution, and the server process was, I believe, too old for macOS to track.

On reconsideration, I don't count it likely this issue or its resolution are related.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo1968. I didn't know about `<kbd>`, ah, as allowlisted inline-html.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved. I don't know how. Perhaps restarting both Brave and iTerm.

When applications other than Brave (and iTerm) are in the foreground, then toggling permissions for iTerm in Security & Privacy > Full Keyboard Access, and restarting it, proved sufficient, to restore use of keyboard toggling outside of Brave.